# Naming elements in Python list

Tags: python

In PHP, I can named element in a list like:

```
<?php
    list($name,$address,$home) = array("Alex","Taiwan","Vietnam");
    echo $address."\n";
?>
```

Output: Taiwan

Can it work the same in Python? I am tired of doing like:

```
list = ["Alex","Taiwan","Vietnam"]
print list[1]
```

Comment: [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use unpacking.

```
name, city, country = ["Alex","Taiwan","Vietnam"]
print name
```

In Python3, you can do much more using the `*` operator.

```
a, *b, c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # a = 1, b = [2, 3, 4], c = 5
```

Refer [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) for more generalizations.

Answer (score 3):

**name tuple** in module `collections` is also helpful:

```
>>> import collections
>>> Data = collections.namedtuple("Data", "name address home")
>>> Data('Alex', 'Taiwan', 'Vietnam')
>>> d = Data('Alex', 'Taiwan', 'Vietnam')
>>> d.name
'Alex'
>>> d.address
'Taiwan'
>>> d.home
'Vietnam'
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want a dictionary:

```
d = {'name': 'Alex', 'address': 'Taiwan', 'home': 'Vietnam'}
print d['address']
```

If you need the ordered list you can make an ordered dict and call values() on it.

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict({'name': 'Alex', 'address': 'Taiwan', 'home': 'Vietnam'})
d.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `namedtuple` data type:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# create a new data type (internally it defines a class ContactData):
ContactData = namedtuple("ContactData", ["name", "city", "state"])

# create an object as instance of our new data type
alex = ContactData("Alex", "Taiwan", "Vietnam")

# access our new object
print(alex)             # output: ContactData(name='Alex', city='Taiwan', state='Vietnam')
print(alex.city)        # output: Taiwan
print(alex[1])          # output: Taiwan
alex[0] = "Alexander"   # set new value
print(alex.name)        # output: Alexander
```